# Remove empty row column headings from Matrix table Chart in power bi

Tags: matrix, charts, powerbi, dax, visualization

Can someone please help me on this one
I want remove empty row column headings from Matrix table Chart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hy8EW.png)
[[[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTYHA.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3gym.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IymH.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGQS0.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DglJh.png)

I have added all the visual Snaps

I have tried adjusting the width of the column.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Power BI will keep showing the totals, even if the value is blank.

What might help from a visual perspective is to switch so that it shows the values on the rows, rather than the columns - this might make it easier to see. The option is under "Values > Options" in the formatting pane.

Hope this helps.